# UIAlertController with UITextfield does not display Title and Message

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Please help me with below issue.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Check"  message:@"What was the value collected?"  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
{
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textField.placeholder = @"What was the value collected?";
}];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) 
{                  
    UITextField *txtValue = alertController.textFields.firstObject;                    
    toCollect = [txtValue.text floatValue];
}]];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have using above code but it shows me result in below screenshot. Not able to display title and message
[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: its float variable that save the text value input in uitextfield.

Comment: your code works fine.

Comment: see if you can reproduce this in different simulators.

Comment: i have tested it in iPad Mini

Comment: I copied your code and ran it on a 9.0 simulator and it works fine. What iOS version are you using?

Comment: I also copied your code  it works fine on a 9.0 simulator

Comment: Where are you calling this code? In the app delegate? In the view controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is the code for create `UIAlertController` for showing Message and title.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Controller"
                                      message:@"Alert Message"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 250, 30)];
lbl.text = @"This is a label";
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[viewController.view addSubview:lbl];

UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 250, 30)];
tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
tf.placeholder = @"Enter your name";
[viewController.view addSubview:tf];

[alertController setValue:viewController forKey:@"contentViewController"];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                               }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"OK action");

                               NSLog(@"Text Value : %@",tf.text);
                           }];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

[image]

For swift you can do same thing like following code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Controller", message: "Alert Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
    title: "Cancel",
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (action) in

}

let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
    title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in

}

alert.addAction(confirmAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

let VC = UIViewController()
VC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


let lbl =  UILabel()
lbl.frame =  CGRectMake(10, 8, 250, 30)
lbl.text = "this is a label"
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
lbl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
VC.view .addSubview(lbl)


let txt = UITextField()
txt.frame =  CGRectMake(10, 35, 250, 30)
txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
txt.placeholder = "enter text"
VC.view .addSubview(txt)


alert.setValue(VC, forKey: "contentViewController")

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Download Demo from Github: https://github.com/nitingohel/NGAlertViewController-Swift2.0

Answer (score 2):

I was tested your code which you posted on here and thats work fine in all simulator as well as devices also in iOS 8.0+ OR if you want to test it in ios 7.0 then you have to use UIAlertview.

Code is : view controller.m

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    float toCollect;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(IBAction)btntapped:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Check"  message:@"What was the value collected?"  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
     {
         textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
         textField.placeholder = @"What was the value collected?";
     }];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        UITextField *txtValue = alertController.textFields.firstObject;

        toCollect = [txtValue.text floatValue];
}]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Snaps of Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be frank your code is working fine. Just a hunch, try adding `[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];` 
this piece of code on main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: its gives me warning -- "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release."

Comment: I dont understand, I see many post the question with uialertcontroller with the same issue. Seems wierd bug on iOS for them!!!

Comment: Same issue when i m using UIAlertView in place of UIAlertController.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for that.

```
if ([UIAlertController class])
    {
        // use UIAlertController
        UIAlertController *alert= [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Folder Name"
                                      message:@"Keep it short and sweet"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                       //Do Some action here
                                                       UITextField *textField = alert.textFields[0];
                                                       NSLog(@"text was %@", textField.text);

                                                   }];
        UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                           NSLog(@"cancel btn");

                                                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                                       }];

        [alert addAction:ok];
        [alert addAction:cancel];

        [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
            textField.placeholder = @"folder name";
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        }];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I modified your code a bit and it worked for me. Basically, I used "show" controller instead of "present".

Here is the snip:

```
-(IBAction)pressMe:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Check"  message:@"What was the value collected?"  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
     {
         textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
         textField.placeholder = @"What was the value collected?";
     }];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        UITextField *txtValue = alertController.textFields.firstObject;

        NSString *string = txtValue.text;
        NSLog(@"String: %@", string);
    }]];
    [self showViewController:alertController sender:nil] 
}
```