# UIAlertController title and message do not appear in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, xcode8

The YES and NO buttons function work as expected, the only problem is that the question `No GPS hardware use Triangulation?` does not appear to inform the user what the alert is about. The application is tabbed.

The entire code for the project including the xcode project files and Info.plist files can be
found on [GitHub](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/iOSCodeChallenge), in case you want to build or debug it.

The title and message of the UIAlertController do not appear for the following UIAlertController:

```
- (UIAlertController*) alertUserNoGPSHardware {
    UIAlertController *alertToPresent = nil;
    NSString* alertTitleString = @"GPS Alert";
    NSString* alertMessage = @"No GPS hardware use Triangulation?";

    if (!hardwareExistsOnDevice && mustUseGPSHardware) {
        alertToPresent = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: alertTitleString message:alertMessage
                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YES" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {mustUseGPSHardware = NO;}];
        [alertToPresent addAction:yesButton];
        UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"NO" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {mustUseGPSHardware = YES;}];
        [alertToPresent addAction:noButton];
    }

    return alertToPresent;
}
```

I've also tried to embed the above code in the function that calls this library routine. The same problem occurs.

```
- (void) setLabelWithGPSLatitudeAndLongitudeWithTimeStampData {
    NSString *actionString = nil;

    if (displayDataModel) {
        if (isFirstGpsClick) {
            // Call to the DataModel library that receives a pointer UIAlertView object from the GPS library implementation
            // If the UIAlertView pointer is nil proceed with the displaying the latitude, longitude and timestamp.
            // If the UIAlertView has a value show the alert, the alert should contain a function to update data in the GPS model.
            // This will enable the user to approve of using WiFi or Radio triangulation when the GPS is not available.
            /*
             * BUG - title and message are not appearing in the alert, the buttons in the alert work as expected
             *          clicking the YES button removes the warning message that there is no GPS hardware and just
             *          returns the data. Clicking the no message displays displays the warning message every time.
             */
            isFirstGpsClick = NO;
            UIAlertController* gpsAlert = [displayDataModel provideGPSAlerters];
            if (gpsAlert) {
                [self presentViewController:gpsAlert animated:NO completion:nil];
                return;
            }
        }
        actionString = [displayDataModel provideGPSLocationData];
    }
    else {
        actionString = @"GPS Button Action Failure: Data Model not created";
    }

    [displayButtonAction setText:actionString];
}
```

I've also tried moving the embedded code into the following 2 functions

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    /*
     * Get the tab bar height from the Application Delegate so that the total vertical space
     * can be calculated.
     */
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if (appDelegate) {
        UITabBarController *TempTabBar = appDelegate.tabBarController;
        if (TempTabBar) {
            // Tab Bar Height is larger than myDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height indicates
            tabBarHeight = TempTabBar.tabBar.frame.size.height * 2.5;
        }
    }

    [self setSubViewSizeVariablesBasedOnViewBounds];
    [self addButtonAndLabels];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.displayModelLibraryInitialization) {
        NSLog(@"In Objective-C Implementation viewDidLoad - unable to initialize displayModelLibrary");
    }
}
```

When I move the UIAlertController into viewWillLayoutSubviews() or viewDidLoad() I get the black screen, not
the alert and not the buttons and labels that should be there.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621525/uialertcontroller-title-and-message-not-appearing) does not apply because the current problem is in Objective-c and not Swift.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843826/uialertcontroller-with-uitextfield-does-not-display-title-and-message) does not apply because no textfield is getting updated.

The code does not use alert builder so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849596/alert-dialogue-title-and-message-are-not-shown) doesn't apply.

**Background**

I am new to programming in Xcode, iOS, Objective-c and Swift. This is my first iOS project. It was
an interview coding challenge.

OSX - El Capitan
Xcode - Version 8.2 (8C38)
Running in the simulator.

Comment: Ran code in simulator, but no alert appears. How does one get the alert?

Comment: Take out the #if 0 #endif that surrounds the code.

Comment: The GitHub version has now had the #if #endif removed. The ObjectiveCViewController.m file will now run the alert.

Comment: I just turned the if 0 into if 1 to get it to kick in. I see the message just fine: Xcode 8.3, using iPhone 7 simulator. One reason for this kind of oddness - your problem - is asking for it to be presented on some thread other than main. I always use "assert([NSThread isMainThread]);" whenever modifying UI. All those GPS delegate calls most likely on background threads.

Comment: Your code looks very professional. Only comment is remove space "- (void) s" -> - (void)s

Comment: @DavidH I switched from iPhone 7 plus to iPhone 7 and it works. I also added the assert you recommended. Spaces will be removed in the next commit as well. Thank you for the clue. It still doesn't work in iPhone 7 plus. I also don't have to start from a Y coordinate greater than 290.0 anymore, although 0.0 still doesn't work right.

Answer (score 1):

I am only answering this so that it doesn't add to StackOverflow unanswered questions (on CodeReview we would call an unaswered question a zombie).

@DavidH helped provide the answer.

It seems that there are a few minor quirks to the iPhone 7 plus simulator in Xcode 8.2. DavidH was able to see the message in the alert in the `iPhone 7 simulator in Xcode 8.3`. I switched to the *iPhone 7 simulator* from the *iPhone 7 plus simulator* and saw the message in the alert.

This indicates there may not have been a problem in the code and that the `iPhone 7 plus simulator in Xcode 8.2` ***may*** be buggy.

Comment: Anyone - feel free to provide an answer or comment.

Comment: Just ran it with 7+ - see the text just fine.

Comment: @DavidH Yes, but I think you're on Sierra with Xcode 8.3, I'm on El Capitan with Xcode 8.2, primarily because when I switched from Snow Leopard only Xcode 8.2 was available and it didn't run on Sierra, or that's what the person at the Genius Bar at the Apple store told me. Xcode 8.3 won't install on El Capitan. You can always add an answer of your own, which I will upvote and probably accept or down vote my answer. Up to you. At the moment I don't have a backup solution and don't want to lose any work I've done so upgrading to Sierra and Xcode 8.3 is not the greatest choice.